# log4j writing to multiple loggers in a multithreaded application

Tags: filter, log4j2

I'm developing a Java application (process) that parses and loads multiple data files into a darabase. This is a multi threaded process.  I'd like to capture the log output from each thread into a separate log file.  I'm using log4j 2.7 and Java 7.  I've looked at the Log4j2 docs and I'm thinking this may be possible using one of the available filters.  I thought of using the Marker filter, but determined it wouldn't work very well.  This is due to the dynamic nature of the data and different Marker objects that that would have to be passed to the Logger methods.  So I'm now thinking that one of the other filters that use keys/values might be better.  But I can't find much documentation on these.  Possibly the DynamicThresholdFilter?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RoutingAppender can do exactly what you need.

The FAQ has a good configuration example: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'll research this further.  Just curious though... What about the idea of instantiating a new Logger in each thread?  And configuring loggers for each possible thread name. I wasn't sure if doing so is less efficient or worse.

Comment: Programmatically reconfiguring is possible, but bear in mind that writing to a file is done by an appender, not a logger. Creating new Loggers is normal. Every class usually creates its own Logger. The point is, how to indicate that your log statements from Thread X end up being routed to FileAppender X. Even if you reconfigure and add the FileAppender programmatically, you still need to route to it somehow. This is what the RoutingAppender is for.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of configuring the different Loggers declaratively in log4j1.xml; one for each possible thread name.  So something like  <Logger name="thread1" level="debug" ...

Comment: <Logger name="thread2" level="debug" ... </Logger>, etc.  And then define specific <appender-ref> elements for each Logger- each pointing to a different file.  
Using the method you recommend, I presume that I would need just one logger and rely on the RoutingAppender's to correctly route output to the respective files.  If what I propose makes any sense and is possible then is that any more or less better?  Just trying to understand what's better or a "best practice".  Thanks again!

Comment: The best practice is to (in your code) obtain loggers as `LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class)`. The resulting Logger will have the name `fully.qualified.classname.of.MyClass`. In your configuration you can use that convention to for example filter by level: if your config has `<Logger name="com.somepackage" level="warn" />` then log statements from *all* classes in that package that are INFO or more verbose will be suppressed. Have you tried RoutingAppender? It was designed to solve that exact problem.

Comment: I'm going to attempt developing my solution using your recommendations.  Thanks so much for the assistance- much appreciated!